# Optimize MySQL on duplicate key update with conditions to update

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have a working solution, but I'm not sure this might be the best solution.

My goal: there's a table (testtable) with a column `status`. When the current status is 'CXL' and a insert query is run, the `statusUpdateDateTime` should be newer than the existing value for that row and if so, for column `status` there should be an extra check. If the previous value was 'CXL' and the current value is 'ACPT', the value should stay at 'CXL', otherwise the value must be updated to the new value.

For the other columns, there's only a 'newer' check necessary.

below is the test table (in practice the unique key will contain multiple columns)

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `rowid` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mappedId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `statusupdatedatetime` datetime(1) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_identifier` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_trade_reporting_status_table` (`mappedId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2
```

this will be my initial insert query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `testtable` (`mappedId`,`status`,`statusupdatedatetime`,`message`,`message_identifier`) VALUES 
(1,'RJCT','2023-02-05 13:39:00.0','Rejected',''), 
(2,'ACPT','2023-02-05 13:39:00.0','Accepted',''),
(3,'PNDG','2023-02-05 13:40:00.0','Pending',''),
(4,'CXL','2023-02-05 13:50:00.0','Accepted','some message')
AS newData
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`testtable`.`status` = 
CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime`
THEN 
(
    CASE WHEN IFNULL(STRCMP(`testtable`.`status`, 'CXL'),-1)=0  AND IFNULL(STRCMP(newData.`status`, 'ACPT'),-1)=0
    THEN 'CXL' 
    ELSE newData.`status`
    END
)
ELSE `testtable`.`status` END
,`testtable`.`message` = CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` THEN newData.`message` ELSE `testtable`.`message` END
,`testtable`.`message_identifier` = CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` THEN newData.`message_identifier` ELSE `testtable`.`message_identifier` END
,`testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` = CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` THEN newData.`statusupdatedatetime` ELSE `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` END;
```

the row with `mappedId`=4 has a `status` value of 'CXL'.

when I run this query, the value stays the same (which is intended). Mind the higher date time and 'ACPT' value for `status`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `testtable` (`mappedId`,`status`,`statusupdatedatetime`,`message`,`message_identifier`) VALUES 
(1,'RJCT','2023-02-05 13:39:00.0','Rejected',''), 
(2,'ACPT','2023-02-05 13:39:00.0','Accepted',''),
(3,'PNDG','2023-02-05 13:40:00.0','Pending',''),
(4,'ACPT','2023-02-05 13:51:00.0','Accepted','some message')
AS newData
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`testtable`.`status` = 
CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime`
THEN 
(
    CASE WHEN IFNULL(STRCMP(`testtable`.`status`, 'CXL'),-1)=0  AND IFNULL(STRCMP(newData.`status`, 'ACPT'),-1)=0
    THEN 'CXL' 
    ELSE newData.`status`
    END
)
ELSE `testtable`.`status` END
,`testtable`.`message` = CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` THEN newData.`message` ELSE `testtable`.`message` END
,`testtable`.`message_identifier` = CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` THEN newData.`message_identifier` ELSE `testtable`.`message_identifier` END
,`testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` = CASE WHEN newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` THEN newData.`statusupdatedatetime` ELSE `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime` END;
```

This all works fine, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

regards,

Matthijs

Comment: This code fails in mysql 8 and mysql does not have strcmp function - is this a function you wrote or are the tags not correct.

Comment: @P.Salmon hi, I'm actually running 8.0.31 (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';) STRCMP is a build in function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I am not familiar with the syntax insert..values..AS do you have a reference for that?

Comment: The 'As NewData' part is used because syntax like status=VALUES(status) is obsolete. You now need to use `tableName`.`ColumnName` = `newDataNew`.`ColumnName`. 
"The use of VALUES() to refer to the new row and columns is deprecated beginning with MySQL 8.0.20, and is subject to removal in a future version of MySQL. Instead, use row and column aliases, as described in the next few paragraphs of this section." 
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Is `rowId` used for anything?  Consider getting rid of it and upgrading the `UNIQUE(mappedId)` to `PRIMARY KEY(mappedId)`

Comment: I got lost with "When the current status is 'CXL' and a insert query is run" -- IODKU cannot be used to insert a row based just on that.

Comment: Hi @RickJames , the RowId is indeed used. The example above is a simplified version of the actual schema. And it does work. Just wondering if this can be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

**Speed**

IODKU does 2 steps for each given row.  Your example has 4 rows.

1. Fetch the row (based on any UNIQUE keys provided in the given row).  This is like a `SELECT` and probably cannot be improved upon.
2. Do one of these, depending on whether a row(s) was found.  Since there is only one `UNIQUE` key involved, only `mappedId` is checked (`rowid` is also unique, but it is not listed).

- If no row found, `INSERT` a new row.
- If row(s) found, `UPDATE` them.

The `CASE` expressions (or any other expressions) take only a small amount of the overall time.  Do not worry about optimizing them.

It seems like `IFNULL( STRCMP(...), ...) = FALSE` could be simplified to `NOT STRCMP(...)` or maybe `STRCMP(...) IS NOT NULL`.  (or something like that)

**Readability**

Since everything seems to depend on

```
 newData.statusupdatedatetime > `testtable`.`statusupdatedatetime`
```

I would look for how to split the one statement into two, based on that.  (Sorry, the query is too complex for me to wrap my head around and come up with a concrete suggestion.)